# How can we use two queries in same click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used the code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=kiran-b946c0f6d;
                                           uid=sa;
                                           pwd=123;
                                           database=employe");

    SqlCommand com=new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Emplo VALUES('"+TextBox2.Text+"'",con);
    com.Parameters.Add("Email_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    com.Parameters["Email_ID"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
    con.Open();

    Label3.Text = "successfully added";
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Email_ID FROM Emplo WHERE Email_ID='" 
                         + TextBox2.Text + "'", 
                         con);

    reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        Label3.Text = "Emailid alraedy exist";
    }

    reader.Dispose();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    da.Fill(ds);

    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

I intended to use Insert values in the database and if there is any duplicity,it will show the error.The duplicity is working properly.But insertion is not properly working.It will show inserted successfully.But the values are not doing insertion.

Comment: **WARNING:** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks.

Comment: WARNING 2: you are messing up data access code with User Interface management, you should split these two different concerns and have all data access logic wrapped in a separated class library which will be the only one able and responsible for data retrieval and database connection.

Comment: WARNING3: You store connection credentials in the source code so your application should be recompiled each time you've updated the credentials, use Application Configuration and ConnectionStrings (enctypted even better) instead

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually calling `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` before overwriting the `com` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't running the insert at all - you set up the command and then overwrite it with your new select command.

Even if you were running the insert at that point your select that is coming after it would always be expected to return true because you've just inserted it. Additionally depending on the database structure if that database field is set to be unique (which seems to be what you are trying to enforce in the code) then I would expect a sql exception to be thrown as you try to insert something which already exists.

What you want to do is run the select to check if it already exists first. Then if it exists you can just stop. If it doesn't exist you can do the insert then.

Or better still write a single SQL statement (better yet a procedure) that does the check at the same time as the insert to try to prevent any possible issues relating to two threads doign the check and finding it doesn't exist and then two threads doing the insert causing one of them to fail most likely.